# Why is Big O notation for constant time execution O(1) instead of O(2)?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I understand that O(1) indicates an algorithm will take a constant amount of execution time regardless of the input dimensions. I also understand that O(N) indicates a linear increase in execution time proportional to the input dimension size.

However, I only know this due to memorizing their definitions. I have no intuition in interpreting O(1) and instead just recall that this means constant time execution. I'm curious how I can understand intuition when reading big O notation.

So for constant time execution O(1), what does the 1 represent? Why not have it be O(2)? 2 is also a constant that is independent of input size N.

Comment: 1 is 2, normalized.

Comment: You divide out constant factors with big O notation, so you never say O(3n) (formally at least).  Obviously 1 is the smallest positive integer constant, so O(1) it is.

Comment: @matt Normalized in what sense and how would this apply to other `O(...)` classes?

Comment: @gct But why do we do that? Writing `O(3n)` is not wrong and I am sure there are some cases where writing `O(3n)` instead of `O(n)` would be reasonable.

Comment: It's because big O is by definition _up to a scalar factor_ already.  So there's a factor k in front of whatever you write already, so by convention we fold any other constants into that.

Comment: @gct Yes, it is by convention. Your initial comment made it seem as if you were saying that writing `O(2)` would be formally incorrect, when it only is unconventional.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The notation `O(...)` means a set of functions. Roughly speaking, `O(f(n))` is the set of functions which don't grow asymptotically faster than `f` does.

The constant function `f(n) = 1` doesn't grow at all, and neither does the constant function `f(n) = 2`, so neither grows asymptotically faster than the other. Also, any other function grows asymptotically faster than `1` if and only if it grows asymptotically faster than `2`. So a function is in the set `O(1)` if and only if it is in the set `O(2)`, meaning they are the same set.

This means you can write `O(2)` and it is strictly correct, but it is simpler (and hence conventional) to write `O(1)`. You can think of this a bit like solving a maths problem where the answer is a fraction; you are expected to write the answer in its simplest form. Strictly speaking, 6/4 is equal to 3/2, but it is conventional to write 3/2.

Comment: I don't understand how every tutorial on Big O notation misses what you've said in your first statement. This clears up everything.

Answer (score 2):

Because when you are evaluating the complexity of a function, what matters for you is the variables. If you find any constant, you put it off.

For example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 2 * N; i++){ print("Hello"); }
```

Your complexity is O(2N), but as what matters for you is the VARIABLES, you take the constants out of the equation, leaving O(N).

Now suppose this:

```
int a = b + c + d;
```

The complexity is obviously constant, but the number of operations isn't only 1, let's say it is 3 (2 operations and 1 attribution). Then you have O(3). We can safely say that O(3) = O(3 * N^0). We follow the same procedure of cutting of the constants, leaving us with O(N^0) = O(1).

Just to clarify, when we are evaluating complexities, we imagine that the variable will assume very big values, such big values that any multiplying constant wouldn't make a difference when the variable goes to infinite, that's why we put it off. The same thing holds for additive constants, for example O(5N + 3) = O(N).

Comment: While your answer is correct, it doesn't really answer *why* we don't usually write e.g. `O(2N)` and `O(2)` and stop there. I think the important point that OP isn't seeing is that this is just by convention. We could be using a convention that requires big-O arguments to always start with the integer `2`, but that would just be inconvenient and so would be a convention of writing `O(1234)` instead of `O(1)`. `O(2)` isn't really more difficult to parse than `O(1)`, but if they are obviously equal, then it is a sensible convention to always prefer one of those.

Comment: Yes, it does. It's clear that we cut every multiplicative constants of the equation, such as 2.

Comment: OK, but why do we do that? It would not be mathematically wrong to not remove multiplicative constants.

Comment: No, because as I said, the important part to measure complexity is the behaviour of the things that CHANGE. If your complexity equation depends on a variable, the growth of the variable dictates how the complexity would be. When you set the variable to very big values, any constant (be it 1, 2, 10^1000) lose its meaning once its effect in the curve will be negligible.

Comment: And this implies that, given multiplicative constants don't make a difference, you are free to use any O(1) / O(30) / ... you want, just as @Yves Daoust said.

Comment: Yes it doesn't matter whether we write `O(1)` or `O(30)`, but OP's question is why we write `O(1)` and not `O(30)`. Your answer makes it seem as if only `O(1)` would be a complete answer, when really both would be correct, only that the latter is unconventional to write.

Answer (score 1):

You are free to use `O(2)`, just like you can use `O(33652 n²- log n)`.

At the risk of seeming weird.

Comment: And that equals `O(n²)`.

Comment: @Daniel: simplifying 33652 n²- log n to n² - log n is a strange idea.